# Finding Time Difference Between Observations in R

Tags: r, datetime

i'm trying to determine the time difference between two observations. The data is broken up by different individuals who each have their own unique ID. I have a dataset which tells me what their status updates to every time it changes, and at what time their status changed. Status can be one of two values, and it always changes to the value it is not (in this case, from Y to N, or N to Y).

The data looks like this:

```
ID Status Time
1    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:00      
2    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:03  
3    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:04      
4    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:06      
1    N     2013-07-01 08:07:07      
2    N     2013-07-01 08:07:23      
5    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:34  
6    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:45  
7    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:47  
1    Y     2013-07-01 08:07:56  
3    N     2013-07-01 08:07:58
```

What I would like to find is the amount of time which passes between each status change for each individual ID -- that is, how long it takes to get from Y to N. And then get summary statistics like the distribution of elapsed times, mean of elapsed times, etc.

So an example output might look like this, recording the three Y to N switches which occurred above (1 switched, 2 switched, and 3 switched)

```
Y to N change    Time elapsed (in seconds)
1                     7 
2                     20
3                     54
```

I'm having a lot of trouble with this for some reason. Right now I have the time in POSIXlt format, and the ID and status as a factor. I have tried using ddply to sort the data by ID and then by timestamp, but this hasn't worked so far. Any advice would be much appreciated!

edit: changed time to actually be in the correct type.

Edit2: ended up writing a solution while waiting for more answers. My way is much uglier than many of the solutions here, but I did:

```
N <- ifelse(df$Status=="N",1,0)
Y <- ifelse(df$Status== "Y",1,0)

#making a vector which is 1 for a row if the item status of the row below it is N
var1 <- N
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  var1[i] <- N[i+1]
}

#making a vector which is TRUE if a row's item status is Y and the row after is N
check <- ifelse(var1==s & var1==1,TRUE,FALSE)
#had to define the last one as FALSE manually because the for loop above would miss the last entry due to how it was constructed
check [50000]=FALSE



#made a loop which finds the time difference for a row's TIME and the row below it, given that "check " is true for that row, and writes that to a results vector.
#here is the results vector
results <- numeric(nrow(df))
#here is the for loop
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(check [i]){
    results[i] <- difftime(df$Time[i],df$Time[i+1])
  }
}
```

I originally had this solved with a for loop, but over the ~1 million rows of my actual dataset it was way too slow, so I did this vectorization stuff. Would these other solutions work on data that large? I will definitely be trying them out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another approach. I tried to leave all data in the final output here. Please note, for demonstration purposes, I modified your data a bit. In my code, I first arranged data by `ID` and `Time`. I, then, changed `Status` (i.e.,Y and N) to 0 and 1 in order to create `group`. Here, `group` can tell us when `Status` changed. If you see a same number going on for a few rows, that means `Status` has not changed. I then, calculated time difference (i.e., `gap`) for each ID. Finally, I changed `gap` values which do not appear in the first row for each group to NA. That is, I made unnecessary gaps NAs. Please note that the first observation for each ID has NA in `gap` as well. `gap` is in second.

```
ann <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,2,1,1,1,3),
                  Status = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y",
                             "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N"),
                  Time = c("2013-07-01 08:07:00", "2013-07-01 08:07:03",
                           "2013-07-01 08:07:04", "2013-07-01 08:07:06",
                           "2013-07-01 08:07:07", "2013-07-01 08:07:23",
                           "2013-07-01 08:07:34", "2013-07-01 08:07:45",
                           "2013-07-01 08:07:47", "2013-07-01 08:07:56",
                           "2013-07-01 08:07:58"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ann$Time <- as.POSIXct(ann$Time)

#   ID Status                Time
#1   1      Y 2013-07-01 08:07:00
#2   2      Y 2013-07-01 08:07:03
#3   3      Y 2013-07-01 08:07:04
#4   4      Y 2013-07-01 08:07:06
#5   1      N 2013-07-01 08:07:07
#6   2      N 2013-07-01 08:07:23
#7   2      Y 2013-07-01 08:07:34
#8   1      Y 2013-07-01 08:07:45
#9   1      Y 2013-07-01 08:07:47
#10  1      N 2013-07-01 08:07:56
#11  3      N 2013-07-01 08:07:58

ann %>%
    arrange(ID, Time) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Status = ifelse(Status == "Y", 1, 0),
           group = cumsum(c(T, diff(Status) != 0)),
           gap = Time - lag(Time)) %>%
    group_by(ID, group) %>%
    mutate(gap = ifelse(row_number() != 1, NA, gap))

#   ID Status                Time group gap
#1   1      1 2013-07-01 08:07:00     1  NA
#2   1      0 2013-07-01 08:07:07     2   7
#3   1      1 2013-07-01 08:07:45     3  38
#4   1      1 2013-07-01 08:07:47     3  NA
#5   1      0 2013-07-01 08:07:56     4   9
#6   2      1 2013-07-01 08:07:03     1  NA
#7   2      0 2013-07-01 08:07:23     2  20
#8   2      1 2013-07-01 08:07:34     3  11
#9   3      1 2013-07-01 08:07:04     1  NA
#10  3      0 2013-07-01 08:07:58     2  54
#11  4      1 2013-07-01 08:07:06     1  NA
```

Comment: Actually one question -- I get an error: "Error: column 'gap' has unsupported type" when trying to run this. Any ideas? Very cool solution though!

Comment: @verybadatthis Which version of `dplyr` do you have? I am using `dplyr_0.3.0.9000`. This is a dev version from Github.

Comment: @verybadatthis My R is version 3.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work on the sample data you provided, but those times are not POSIXlt. This finds the first `Y` time and the first `N` time, removes any IDs that don't have a transition from `Y` to `N`, and subtracts the first `Y` time from the first `N` time.

```
library('dplyr')

df <- read.table(text = "ID Status Time
1    Y     1
2    Y     2
3    Y     3.5
4    Y     4
1    N     5.8
2    N     6
5    Y     7
6    Y     8
7    Y     8.1
1    Y     11
3    N     12", header = TRUE)
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID) # convert ID to factor

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Status) %>%
  summarize(Time = min(Time)) %>%
  filter("N" %in% Status & "Y" %in% Status) %>%
  summarize(Time_elapsed = Time[Status == "N"] - Time[Status == "Y"])
```

Result:

```
  ID Time_elapsed
1  1          4.8
2  2          4.0
3  3          8.5
```

Comment: Sorry, I was dumb and did not put them into POSIXlt format. Let me edit the original question, I can see how that causes confusion. As written the code doesn't work for POSIXlt type times, but I'm going to see if I can turn my times into integers and then use your solution. One quick question: would this code be able to deal with a single ID which has many status changes? For example, Y -> N -> Y -> N -> Y? At first glance it looks like it only takes the first occurrence for each ID. Thank again for the help though!

Comment: You can use `dput()` to paste a chunk of your actual data with the POSIXlt values. This code will not work for multiple status changes for a single ID. Didn't realize this was necessary. If you post updated data I'll try to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @verybadatthis I don't understand what you want your output to look like. In your comment you say you want to see all the status changes for each ID, but the example output you gave in your question doesn't reflect this. Can you clarify?