# Partitioning data to determine (ordered) time between observations

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, partitioning

I am not 100% sure how to formulate my question because I don't know the formal names are for what it is that I am trying to do with my dataset. Based on previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724448/finding-time-difference-between-observations-in-r), there appears to be some way to address what I am trying to, but I am unable at making the logical jump from their problem to my own.

I have attached a sample of my data [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d).

The first thing I did with my data was add a column indicating which species (sps) are predators (coded as 1) and which species are prey (coded as 0).

```
#specify which are predators and prey
d1 = d1 %>%
    group_by(sps) %>% #grouped by species
    mutate(pp=ifelse(sps %in% c("MUXX", "MUVI","MEME"), 1,0)) #mutate to specify predators as 1 and prey as 0
```

My data is structured as such:

```
head(d1) #visualize the first few lines of the data
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   sps [4]
 ID       date    km   culv.id   type   sps   time    pp
<int>     <fctr> <dbl>  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
1    2012-06-19    80     A      DCC   MICRO   2:19    0
2    2012-06-21    80     A      DCC   MUXX   23:23    1
3    2012-07-15    80     A      DCC   MAMO   11:38    0
4    2012-07-20    80     A      DCC   MICRO  22:19    0
5    2012-07-29    80     A      DCC   MICRO  23:03    0
6    2012-08-07    80     A      DCC   PRLO    2:04    0
```

Here is also the output for `dput(head(d1))`:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L), date = c("2012-06-19", "2012-06-21", "2012-07-15", "2012-07-20", "2012-07-29", "2012-08-07" ), km = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), culv.id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), type = c("DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC"), sps = c("MICRO", "MUXX", "MAMO", "MICRO", "MICRO", "PRLO" ), time = c("2:19", "23:23", "11:38", "22:19", "23:03", "2:04" ), pp = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "date", "km", "culv.id", "type", "sps", "time", "pp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L ), class = "data.frame")
```

I also converted the time and date using the following code:

```
d1$datetime=strftime(paste(d1$date,d1$time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',usetz=FALSE) #converting the date/time into a new format
```

The (most) relevant columns are date, time, and pp (where 1 = predator species and 0 = prey species).

I am now trying to figure out how to extract the following information (average +/- std):

1. average time between prey-prey observations
2. average time between prey-predator observations
3. average time between predator-predator observations
4. average time between predator-prey observations

> To put one of these examples (#2) into words:
>
> What is the average time between when a prey species (pp = 0) is first seen followed by a predator species (pp = 1)?

I am trying to figure out how to do this for my dataset overall first. I think that once I figure out how to do that, it should be fairly straightforward to restrict the data.

Comment: Can you include the result of `dput(head(d1))` so we can reproduce your data structure?

Comment: @VictorFreg How can I restrict it so that it does not export hundreds of lines of output?

Comment: `head()` should only output 6 lines by default

Comment: @LukeC When I use `head()` as shown above, it outputs only 6 lines (that output is in my original question). But when I use `dput(head(d1))` it outputs lots and lots of lines.

Comment: Does it look anything like `structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L), date = c("2012-06-19", 
"2012-06-21", "2012-07-15", "2012-07-20", "2012-07-29", "2012-08-07"
), km = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), culv.id = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A"), type = c("DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", 
"DCC"), sps = c("MICRO", "MUXX", "MAMO", "MICRO", "MICRO", "PRLO"
), time = c("2:19", "23:23", "11:38", "22:19", "23:03", "2:04"
), pp = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "date", "km", 
"culv.id", "type", "sps", "time", "pp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: That's exactly it, I'll test in a second and edit the answer if needed.

Comment: @LukeC Sort of. It looks more like `structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L), date = structure(c(21L, 23L, 47L, 52L, 61L, 70L), .Label = c("2012-05-30", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-01", "2012-06-02", "2012-06-03", "2012-06-04", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-06", "2012-06-07", "2012-06-08", "2012-06-09", "2012-06-10", "2012-06-11", "2012-06-12", "2012-06-13",` but goes on for too many lines to reproduce here.

Comment: That's weird! If you did `dput(head(d1))` then I'm not sure what's happening- however, the output I've shown should reproduce the first 6 lines of your `df` with your `pp` column, so feel free to just edit that into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the piece on the comments as an example:

```
d1 = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L), date = c("2012-06-19", "2012-06-21", "2012-07-15", "2012-07-20", "2012-07-29", "2012-08-07" ), km = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), culv.id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), type = c("DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC"), sps = c("MICRO", "MUXX", "MAMO", "MICRO", "MICRO", "PRLO" ), time = c("2:19", "23:23", "11:38", "22:19", "23:03", "2:04" ), pp = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "date", "km", "culv.id", "type", "sps", "time", "pp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L ), class = "data.frame")
```

We add the datetime column just as you specified:

```
d1$datetime=strftime(paste(d1$date,d1$time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',usetz=FALSE)
```

First, add a column indicating which sequence of happened prey/predator and the time between observations (we remove the first row because there is no information about the previous observation). Note that, the `timedif` is a numerical value indicating the number of days.

```
d1 = d1 %>% mutate(prev = lag(pp))
d1 = d1 %>% mutate(timedif = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(datetime) - lag(as.POSIXct(datetime))))
d1 = d1[2:nrow(d1),] %>% mutate(seque = as.factor(paste0(pp,prev)))
```

At this point, your table looks like

```
> d1
  ID       date km culv.id type   sps  time pp         datetime prev   timedif seque
1  2 2012-06-21 80       A  DCC  MUXX 23:23  1 2012-06-21 23:23    0  2.877778    10
2  3 2012-07-15 80       A  DCC  MAMO 11:38  0 2012-07-15 11:38    1 23.510417    01
3  4 2012-07-20 80       A  DCC MICRO 22:19  0 2012-07-20 22:19    0  5.445139    00
4  5 2012-07-29 80       A  DCC MICRO 23:03  0 2012-07-29 23:03    0  9.030556    00
5  8 2012-08-07 80       A  DCC  PRLO  2:04  0 2012-08-07 02:04    0  8.125694    00
```

After that, just take the wanted statistics for each group by using

```
avg = d1 %>% group_by(seque) %>% summarise(mean(timedif))
sdevs = d1 %>% group_by(seque) %>% summarise(sd(timedif))
```

We obtain

```
>avg
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   seque `mean(timedif)`
  <fctr>           <dbl>
1     00        7.533796
2     01       23.510417
3     10        2.877778

> sdevs
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   seque `sd(timedif)`
  <fctr>         <dbl>
1     00      1.864554
2     01            NA
3     10            NA
```

Note that the standard deviation is not computed because we only have one observation in the sample dataset for these categories.

Comment: @VictorFreg I posted the data online in the original post. When I try the code using the data posted, I can only get  the first line to work, but after the first `mutate` it doesn't work.

Comment: Just finished editing, it works for this small example now.

Comment: I have two questions about the output. 1) what are the units for  `timedif`? 2) Using the sample dataset posted, I get output that has NA's, why is this occurring? (I will add a sample in the original question.)

Comment: 1) The units for `timedif` is number of days (which has decimals because there is also the hours information).  2) NA appears because in these 6 lines, the sequences 01 and 10 only appear one time, and therefore, the sample deviation is not defined (the sample deviation statistics only makes sense for a set of 2 or more values).

Comment: Okay. Thank you for clarifying! Sorry, I meant NA's in my output (where it says `2   0NA              NA` for example). I posted the output at the end of the question.

Comment: I just checked your edit, I'd recommend you to start a new R session (clean the environment) and retry running the complete code in the answer, as for example, the `seque` should have been transformed in a factor in your result. Often, when re-writing code, the results gets weird because of remaining variables from the previous try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am still not able to reproduce your solution with the code I posted.

Comment: Do you think I should post a new question to try to get the problem I am having addressed?

Comment: I think so. There is something wrong with the behavior of the lag function. Try using `dplyr::lag` instead of `lag` and a possibly related question is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706633/dplyr-lag-function-returns-nas

Comment: I ended up posting it as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956426/dplyr-function-returning-false-nas. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` (and `lubridate`) version that might address your problem:

Using a selection of your posted data (posted at bottom), with a slight modification to your `datetime` creation so that the format works with `data.table`:

```
d1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(d1$date,d1$time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

Convert to a data table:

```
d1 <- as.data.table(d1)
```

Calculate time differences for equal `pp` values for animals by specialization (prey or predator), less than (pred to prey), or greater than (prey to pred).

```
d1$class.class <-  d1[d1, difftime(x.datetime, i.datetime, units = "days"), 
                   on = .(datetime > datetime, pp == pp), mult = "first"]

d1$prey.pred <-d1[d1, x.datetime - i.datetime, 
                   on = .(datetime > datetime, pp > pp ), mult = "first"]

d1$pred.prey <- d1[d1, x.datetime - i.datetime, 
                   on = .(datetime > datetime, pp < pp), mult = "first"]
```

Gives you a column for each:

```
> head(d1[, 7:ncol(d1)])
    time pp            datetime    class.class      prey.pred     pred.prey
1:  2:19  0 2012-06-19 02:19:00 26.388194 days  2.877778 days       NA days
2: 23:23  1 2012-06-21 23:23:00 74.177083 days        NA days 23.51042 days
3: 11:38  0 2012-07-15 11:38:00  5.445139 days 50.666667 days       NA days
4: 22:19  0 2012-07-20 22:19:00  9.030556 days 45.221528 days       NA days
5: 23:03  0 2012-07-29 23:03:00  8.125694 days 36.190972 days       NA days
6:  2:04  0 2012-08-07 02:04:00  1.911111 days 28.065278 days       NA days
```

And you can get summary statistics as you like:

```
d1[by = sps,, .(mean.same.class = mean(class.class, na.rm = TRUE), 
                sd.same.class = sd(class.class, na.rm = TRUE),
                mean.prey.pred = mean(prey.pred, na.rm = TRUE),
                sd.prey.pred = sd(prey.pred, na.rm = TRUE),
                mean.pred.prey = mean(pred.prey, na.rm = TRUE),
                sd.pred.prey = sd(pred.prey, na.rm = TRUE))]

     sps mean.same.class sd.same.class mean.prey.pred sd.prey.pred mean.pred.prey sd.pred.prey
1: MICRO   7.886237 days     8.0547631  18.80733 days    15.504646       NaN days           NA
2:  MUXX  42.073611 days    45.4011658       NaN days           NA  13.01366 days     9.315697
3:  MAMO   5.445139 days            NA  50.66667 days           NA       NaN days           NA
4:  PRLO   2.475694 days     0.7984414  26.62708 days     2.033914       NaN days           NA
5:  LEAM   2.897222 days            NA  10.11597 days           NA       NaN days           NA
```

Libraries: `data.table`, `lubridate`

Data:

```
> dput(d1)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15200L, 15201L, 15199L, 15177L, 15178L, 15204L, 15205L
), date = c("2012-06-19", "2012-06-21", "2012-07-15", "2012-07-20", 
"2012-07-29", "2012-08-07", "2012-08-08", "2012-08-09", "2012-08-13", 
"2012-08-13", "2012-08-25", "2012-08-27", "2012-09-04", "2012-09-09", 
"2012-09-11", "2012-09-14", "2012-09-23", "2012-09-26", "2012-09-27"
), km = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), culv.id = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A"), type = c("DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", 
"DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", 
"DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC", "DCC"), sps = c("MICRO", "MUXX", 
"MAMO", "MICRO", "MICRO", "PRLO", "MICRO", "PRLO", "MICRO", "MICRO", 
"LEAM", "MICRO", "MUXX", "MICRO", "MICRO", "MUXX", "MICRO", "MICRO", 
"MICRO"), time = c("2:19", "23:23", "11:38", "22:19", "23:03", 
"2:04", "23:56", "23:06", "0:04", "0:46", "0:51", "22:23", "3:38", 
"21:08", "0:40", "2:55", "22:09", "20:46", "3:20"), pp = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("ID", 
"date", "km", "culv.id", "type", "sps", "time", "pp"), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

**Edit:**

I'm not really sure about mixing `tidyverse` and `data.table` ideologies, but you could potentially do what you described in comments using `do`. For example, make a modified version of `df`:

```
d1 <- as.data.table(d1)
d1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(d1$date,d1$time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
d1Mod <- d1
d1Mod$km[10:nrow(d1Mod)] <- 90
```

Then, define the `data.table` bit as a function:

```
foo <- function(df_) {
    df_$class.class <-  df_[df_, difftime(x.datetime, i.datetime, units = "days"),
                          on = .(datetime > datetime, pp == pp), mult = "first"]

    df_$prey.pred <-df_[df_, x.datetime - i.datetime,
                      on = .(datetime > datetime, pp > pp ), mult = "first"]

    df_$pred.prey <- df_[df_, x.datetime - i.datetime,
                       on = .(datetime > datetime, pp < pp), mult = "first"]

    return(df_)
}
```

Running `d1 %>% group_by(km) %>% do(foo(as.data.table(.)))` gets you the same output as in the original answer above (since all `km` values are 80). If you run it on the modified `d1Mod` you get an output that *looks* like it has been grouped by `km`:

```
> d1Mod %>% 
+     group_by(km) %>%
+     do(foo(as.data.table(.)))
# A tibble: 19 x 12
# Groups:   km [2]
      ID date          km culv.id type  sps   time     pp datetime            class.class     prey.pred      pred.prey     
   <int> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dttm>              <time>          <time>         <time>        
 1     1 2012-06-19    80 A       DCC   MICRO 2:19      0 2012-06-19 02:19:00 26.3881944 days  2.877778 days        NA days
 2     2 2012-06-21    80 A       DCC   MUXX  23:23     1 2012-06-21 23:23:00         NA days        NA days 23.510417 days
 3     3 2012-07-15    80 A       DCC   MAMO  11:38     0 2012-07-15 11:38:00  5.4451389 days        NA days        NA days
 4     4 2012-07-20    80 A       DCC   MICRO 22:19     0 2012-07-20 22:19:00  9.0305556 days        NA days        NA days
 5     5 2012-07-29    80 A       DCC   MICRO 23:03     0 2012-07-29 23:03:00  8.1256944 days        NA days        NA days
 6     8 2012-08-07    80 A       DCC   PRLO  2:04      0 2012-08-07 02:04:00  1.9111111 days        NA days        NA days
 7     9 2012-08-08    80 A       DCC   MICRO 23:56     0 2012-08-08 23:56:00  0.9652778 days        NA days        NA days
 8    10 2012-08-09    80 A       DCC   PRLO  23:06     0 2012-08-09 23:06:00  3.0402778 days        NA days        NA days
 9    11 2012-08-13    80 A       DCC   MICRO 0:04      0 2012-08-13 00:04:00         NA days        NA days        NA days
10    12 2012-08-13    90 A       DCC   MICRO 0:46      0 2012-08-13 00:46:00 12.0034722 days 22.119444 days        NA days
11    13 2012-08-25    90 A       DCC   LEAM  0:51      0 2012-08-25 00:51:00  2.8972222 days 10.115972 days        NA days
12    14 2012-08-27    90 A       DCC   MICRO 22:23     0 2012-08-27 22:23:00 12.9479167 days  7.218750 days        NA days
13 15200 2012-09-04    90 A       DCC   MUXX  3:38      1 2012-09-04 03:38:00  9.9701389 days        NA days  5.729167 days
14 15201 2012-09-09    90 A       DCC   MICRO 21:08     0 2012-09-09 21:08:00  1.1472222 days  4.240972 days        NA days
15 15199 2012-09-11    90 A       DCC   MICRO 0:40      0 2012-09-11 00:40:00 12.8951389 days  3.093750 days        NA days
16 15177 2012-09-14    90 A       DCC   MUXX  2:55      1 2012-09-14 02:55:00         NA days        NA days  9.801389 days
17 15178 2012-09-23    90 A       DCC   MICRO 22:09     0 2012-09-23 22:09:00  2.9423611 days        NA days        NA days
18 15204 2012-09-26    90 A       DCC   MICRO 20:46     0 2012-09-26 20:46:00  0.2736111 days        NA days        NA days
19 15205 2012-09-27    90 A       DCC   MICRO 3:20      0 2012-09-27 03:20:00         NA days        NA days        NA days
```

However, you'll have to do some checking to make sure that the calculations are actually doing what you need- I don't have example output or actual `km`/`year` info to truth these results against (read: I don't know what I'm looking at!).

Note also that I think `arrange` is irrelevant for the operations here, considering that the `datetime` gets sorted in the function.

Comment: I realize it's been a lifetime, but I have gone back and tried to use your code to get those species-specific means. When I try the first line (the code starting with `d1$class.class`), I get this error `Error in `[.data.frame`(d3, d3, difftime(x.datetime, i.datetime, units = "days"),  : unused arguments (on = .(datetime > datetime, pp == pp), mult = "first")`. Any suggestions? If I post this as a new question might you be able to look into it?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist - Yeah, ancient history! Sorry, I can't replicate your error- I just tried the code again (copying the above into a new file, and using the sample data `d1`) and it still gives me the same output as shown above. I am using the most recent release versions of `data.table` and `lubridate`. Do you have any packages installed that might be masking the functions from those packages?

Comment: That did it! My `data.table` package was out of date. I was using 1.11.0 not 1.12.2. Thank you!

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I need to first arrange(datetime) %>% group_by("km", "year") but then the code you posted doesn't work. Any suggestions for work arounds?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist - Right on! As to your second comment- `year` is not a column in the example data given here. Is this related to your [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172464/calculating-time-lag-between-sequential-events-after-grouping-for-subsets) with the updated example data?

Comment: Yes, it is related to that question. And no, `year` isn't a column in the example data, but even when I try `arrange(datetime) %>% group_by("km")` the `difftime` function does not work.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist - I'm not sure if it's frowned upon to mix `tidyverse` and `data.table` approaches, but see my edits for one option. Also, did you mean to ask this on the actual accepted answer for this question? I see that they used a `tidyverse` approach.

Comment: Back then, I didn't realize it, but yes. So, thank you!